# MySQL: Select from coma separated list / list as table? "SELECT a FROM (1, 2, 3)"

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is it possible to do something like this (obviously this syntax does not work):

```
SELECT a FROM (1, 2, 3)
```

to get this:

```
| a |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
```

?

That is I want to make rows from coma separated list, without using any table, or at least without creating table in db (maybe this is possible using something like temporary table?).

Maybe it is possible to get column of given values without using select, that is using some other sql statment? If it is not possible in MySQL, but possible in some other SQL it still would be interesting to know.

Comment: @SashiKant Several 1000 others can't as well...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT 1 a UNION ALL SELECT 2 a UNION ALL SELECT 3 a;
```

Comment: Very sweet, nice idea, though statement gets a bit long:) But I believe you are very likely to have an accepted answer! :)

Comment: @aykut : Because you are not elimination any duplicates I would recommend using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

Comment: @morphles, can you give a scenario that you want? I did'nt figure out your problem :/

Comment: I work with app,that has texts in multiple language,and we do not have frontend for some entering some texts. So I insert them like this(by default at start text in all languages are same): INSERT INTO translations (name, translation, lang_id) SELECT 'somename','some_trans',id FROM languages. With such select I should be able to add join and insert translations for multiple names in one query.Admittedly this is kinda lame use case, but I bet I'll find more productive uses, now that I have ways to do this. Admittedly it's a bit of a fail on my part that I couldn't figure out a solution myself:)

Comment: Do you wanna populate all missing translation texts of a language with texts of existing language? Is it one time job? If it is, i think u can do it in your application layer.

Comment: @aykut : Please read [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/) and you will get what I am referring too. I just think because you are not in any need of the distinct values you should use the `UNION ALL` instead of the `UNION` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Would a temporary table be an option? Then I would have a suggestion which, admittedly, has more than 1 query:

```
-- DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_list IF EXISTS;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_list (a INT);
INSERT INTO tmp_list (a) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
SELECT a FROM tmp_list;
```

Answer (score 2):

> *If it is not possible in MySQL, but possible in some other SQL it still would be interesting to know.*

In standard SQL this would be something like this

```
select *
from ( values (1), (2), (3) ) t
```

This works at least in PostgreSQL and DB2.

In PostgreSQL you can give the column a name by extending the alias (not sure if that column aliasing is part of the SQL standard).

```
select *
from ( values (1), (2), (3) ) t (id)
```

The following is an alternative to the above using a common table expression.

```
with my_values (id) as (
  values (1), (2), (3)
)
select *
from my_values;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since MariaDB v10.3.3 and MySQL v8.0.19 you can now do *exactly* that!

See docs:  [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/table-value-constructors/), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html)

**MariaDB:**

```
WITH mylist (a) AS (VALUES (1),(2),(3))
SELECT a FROM mylist
```

I used a `WITH` here because MariaDB doesn't supply nice column names for `VALUES ...`.  You can use it in a union without column names:

```
SELECT 1 AS a UNION ALL VALUES (2),(3)
```

And although the docs don't appear to mention it, you can even use it as a top-level query:

```
VALUES (1),(2),(3) ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

The actual column names are in fact the just first row of values, so you can even do this (though it's inelegant, and you can run into duplicate column name errors):

```
SELECT `4` AS a FROM (VALUES (4),(5),(6)) mylist
```

---

**MySQL:**

<s>I don't have an instance of MySQL v8.0.19 to test against right now, but according to the docs</s> [*EDIT:  Tested successfully on MySQL v8.0.23 using  dbfiddle.uk, see links in comment #2*] either of these should work:

```
SELECT column_0 AS a FROM (VALUES ROW(1), ROW(2), ROW(3)) mylist

SELECT a FROM (VALUES ROW(1), ROW(2), ROW(3)) mylist(a)
```

Unlike MariaDB, MySQL supplies automatic column names column_0, column_1, column_2, etc., and also supports renaming all of a subquery's columns when referencing it.

I'm not sure, but [this dev worklog page](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=10358) seems to suggest that MySQL <s>has also implemented</s> [*EDIT:  not implemented yet, as of v8.0.26*] the shorter sytax (omitting "ROW", like MariaDB), or that they might at some poiint in the near future.

Comment: Neither of the solutions that you provided worked on MySQL

Comment: @dnetix I beg to differ:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6a4daaa372a3c07015ebb7cee98253d  and https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fe14d2dcfcd3d90f7b5775074a8715c  are you sure you tested on v8.0.19+?

Comment: Using 5.7.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Every one of the commands responded with "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; ..."

The solution was creating a temporary table to make the join, this is a shorter list, the original was like 1000 bines to check

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_list (bin varchar(6));
INSERT INTO tmp_list (bin) VALUES ('365454'), ('360218'), ('360218'), ('364172'), ('364173'), ('364172'); 
SELECT bin, name FROM tmp_list LEFT JOIN provider_bin ON provider_bin.bine = tmp_list.bin WHERE provider_bin.bine IS NOT NULL;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_list;

Comment: @dnetix The first line of this answer clearly states: "Since MariaDB v10.3.3 and MySQL **v8.0.19** you can now do...".  Since you are using only **v5.7.23** of MySQL, this answer *does not apply* to your setup, and the errors you are getting are therefore entirely to be expected.  Please do not down-vote or post misleadingly general comments like "It doesn't work" when the answer **explicitly states that it's not applicable to the version of MySQL you are using!**